# removing an object (\institute{}) from Beamer title page

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles

I want to remove the `\institute` from the title page because I used it as `\insertinstitute` in `\setbeamertemplate{footline}` to customize `footline{}`. Apparently, non of the code below works. Many thanks in advance.

```
\setbeamertemplate{institute}{}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[noinstitute]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\institute` locally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Test}
\institute{My institute}

\begin{document}
{
  \institute{}
  \begin{frame}
    \maketitle % title page without institute
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```